# how to add string in autoincreement in VB.net

Tags: vb.net

I have a question how to add string when auto incrementin VB.net

For example I have table named Sales

```
Transaction_number | Supplier  | Price  | quantity | total|

 CG001             | Donny     |  $3    |    7     | $21  |
 CG002             | Albert    |  $2    |    5     | $10  |
```

I want if I add data to transaction_number automatically autoincreement with string CG003,CG004 etc....

Please help me how to solve this problem...Thank You

Comment: is this a database table? which database you are using?

Comment: Could you provide us with more information and what you've tried?

Answer (score 1):

You would use two columns.  The first column would be a standard auto-incrementing integer, e.g. an identity in SQL Server.  You would then add another text column and set a formula to calculate its value based on the integer in the first column.